# Postgresql Null value populates left table when doing a left join. Why is this happening?

Tags: postgresql

When I make the query:

`"select * from asset a where (a.login_id = $1) and (a.status = 'pub')";`

I get back the expected result:

```
{
  id: 23f8jfj8gh2,
  name: 'Asset1',
  status: 'pub',
  create_date: 2020-11-12T07:00:00.000Z,
  ...
}
```

But when I add a left join onto the query like this:

```
"select * from asset a left join asset_image i on (a.id = i.asset_id) where (a.login_id = $1) and (a.status = 'pub')";
```

I get back:

```
{
  id: null,  <---- THIS NULL VALUE for the asset id
  name: 'Asset1',
  status: 'pub',
  create_date: 2020-11-12T07:00:00.000Z,
  ...
  asset_id: null,
  orig_name: null,
  mimetype: null,
  created: null
}
```

I am new to SQL, and I have looked at the docs for left joins, but I can't seem to figure out exactly where this is going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably the `*` in `SELECT *`, which is something that you should always avoid in code.

If the table `asset_image` also has a column named `id`, your result set will contain *two* columns named `id`. You are probably looking at the wrong one.

Using `SELECT *` gives you no control over the columns you get in the result set, their name and their order. You should use an explicit column list and give columns with the same name in both tables an alias that allows you to disambiguate them.

Answer (score 2):

If the `asset_image` table contains its own column with the name of `id` when your query gets no match between `(a.id = i.asset_id)` it will overwrite the `id` field with null.

You may need to define each tables `id` column with a more unique name eg.

- `asset_id` to replace `id` in the `asset` table
- `image_id` to replace `id` in the `asset_image` table

Comment: That makes sense. I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That answer is on the right track, but it misses the point that there may be two `id` columns in the result set.